# Transferring code from notepad ++ to command prompt

Tags: java, arrays, enums, polynomials

I'm relatively new to java, so I wouldn't be surprised if I'm missing something obvious here. Anyways, I made a code that finds the roots of a polynomial using the Bisection method. I thought the program was all well and dandy until I pasted it from notepad++ to command prompt, where I ended up getting a bunch of "class, interface, or enum expected" errors after compiling it using javac. Everything seems fine in the code itself, so I've deduced that I've made one of the following two errors: either something wrong occurred while I was copying and pasting into command prompt, or I actually did create an error in my code that I didn't catch. Could someone tell me just what I did wrong? It may be a minor fix, but I just don't know how to change it to get my code to work. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Roots {

  public static int degree;
  public static double[] coArrayC;
  public static double[] coArrayD;
  public static int coeffVal;

  public static void main( String[] args ){
        double resolution = 0.01;
        double tolerance = 0.0000001;
        double threshold = 0.001;

        double rightEndPt;
        double leftEndPt;
        int polyRootPointer = 0;
        int diffRootPointer = 0;

        boolean rootAns = false;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter the degree: "); //prompts user to enter the correct degree of the polynomial
        degree = sc.nextInt();

        coeffVal = degree + 1; //the coefficient is one more than the number of degrees
        System.out.print("Enter " + coeffVal + " coefficients: "); //adds in the value of the polynomial coefficient in to the line that prompts the user to specify which coefficients are in the function
        double[] coefficients = new double[coeffVal]; //initialization of array, a bunch of doubles that represent the coefficients of the user's polynomial
        coArrayC = new double[coeffVal]; //naming the array

        double[] rootArray = new double[degree];//another array for the degrees of the polynomial

        coArrayD = new double[coeffVal]; //and assigning it a name

        for(int i = 0; i < coeffVal; i++) {
              coefficients[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter the right and left endpoints, in that order: "); //prompts user to enter the interval limits
        rightEndPt = sc.nextDouble();
        leftEndPt = sc.nextDouble();


        diff(coefficients); //calculates coefficients of derivative polynomial

        for (double i = leftEndPt; i < rightEndPt-resolution; i = i + resolution){ //
              if (isPositive(coArrayD, i) != isPositive(coArrayD, i+resolution) || isPositive(coArrayD, i) == 0) {
                    rootArrayDeriv[diffRootPointer] = findRoot(coArrayD, i, i+resolution, tolerance);
                    diffRootPointer++;
              }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rootArrayDeriv.length; i++) {
              double tempValue;
              tempValue = poly(coefficients, rootArrayDeriv[i]);
              tempValue = Math.abs(tempValue);
              if (tempValue < threshold) {
                    rootArray[polyRootPointer] = rootArrayDeriv[i];
                    polyRootPointer++;
                    rootAns = true;
              }
        }

        for (double i = leftEndPt; i < rightEndPt-resolution; i = i + resolution){
              if (isPositive(coefficients, i) != isPositive(coefficients, i+resolution) || isPositive(coefficients, i) == 0) {
                    rootArray[polyRootPointer] = findRoot(coefficients, i, i+resolution, tolerance);
                    polyRootPointer++;
                    rootAns = true;
              }
        }

        //Arrays.sort(rootArray); //sorts array from lowest to highest

        if (rootAns == true) {
            System.out.println("Sorry - no roots were found in the specified interval.");
                    }
              }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < rootArray.length; i++) {
                if (rootArray[i] != 0.0) {
                    System.out.printf("Root found at %.5f\n :" Arrays.sort(rootArray[i])); //if roots are found, list them as an output, with five decimal places of accuracy
        }
  }

  static double poly(double[] C, double x){
        double polySum = 0;
        coArrayC[0] = C[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < coArrayC.length; i++){
              coArrayC[i] = C[i]*(Math.pow(x, i)); //multiplies each coefficient by the designated power of X
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < coArrayC.length; i++){
              polySum = polySum + coArrayC[i]; //accumulates the sum of of all the terms, after the coeff. were multiplied to their respective powers.
        }
        return(polySum);

  }

  static double[] diff(double[] C){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < degree; i++){
              coArrayD[i] = (i+1)*C[i+1]; //newly allocated array D containing coeff. of the polynomial that is the derivative of the polynomial with coeff. array C.
        }
        return(coArrayD);
  }

  static double findRoot(double[] C, double a, double b, double tolerance){ //using bisection method; similar to findRoot.java in cmps webpage.
        double root = 0.0 , residual;
        while ( Math.abs(b - a) > tolerance ) { 
              root = (a + b) / 2.0;
              residual = poly(C, root);
              if (poly(C, a) < 0 && poly(C, b) < 0) { 
                    if (residual > 0)
                          b = root;
                    else
                          a = root;                       
              } else if (poly(C, a) > 0 && poly(C, b) > 0) { 
                    if (residual > 0)
                          a = root;  //replace left endpoint
                    else
                          b = root; //replace right endpoint
              }
        }
        return(root);
  }

  static int isPositive(double[] C, double a){
        double endpointTempA;
        endpointTempA = poly(C, a);
        if (endpointTempA < 0) {
              return(1);
        } else if (endpointTempA > 0) {
              return(2);
        } else {
              return(0); 
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: `pasted it from notepad++ to command prompt` Can you clarify what you mean by this? How are you trying to compile/run the source file?

Comment: Post the stack trace here.

Comment: Are you literally copying and pasting the source code into the command prompt window? That's not how you normally compile and run a Java program. Save the source code in a file named `Roots.java` using Notepad++ and then compile it using the `javac` command at the command prompt. See Oracle's [Hello World Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html) for a more detailed overview of how to compile and run your program.

Comment: No, I did use javac. But after wards, I get a slew of errors specified by what i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `}` too many here:

```
    if (rootAns == true) {
        System.out.println("Sorry - no roots were found in the specified interval.");
                }
          }
    } else {
```

If you indent your code properly, it's easier to see these kinds of errors. Remove the two `}` that don't belong there:

```
    if (rootAns == true) {
        System.out.println("Sorry - no roots were found in the specified interval.");
    } else {
```

There's also a missing `,` here, and you shouldn't pass a single `double` to `Arrays.sort`, but the whole array

```
System.out.printf("Root found at %.5f\n :"Arrays.sort(rootArray[i]));
```

Should be:

```
System.out.printf("Root found at %.5f\n :", Arrays.sort(rootArray));
```

And a missing `}`.

Instead of writing a whole program at once and then trying to compile it, write it little by little, and compile it each time you have for example a complete method. That way you avoid getting a mountain of little errors that confuse you.

Comment: quick question - why did you change rootArray[i] to just rootArray?

Comment: Because `rootArray[i]` is just a single `double` number. You can't sort a number. You wanted to sort the array `rootArray`, not the just the one number at index `i`of `rootArray`.